# Node module for OData action

Tags: node.js, odata

For calling OData action, we need to construct proper URL. This URL construction is a standard process. Is there any Node module for supporting this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript's builtin [encodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) function.

```
encodeURI("http://google.com?name=Sameer Kanikdale")
// http://google.com?name=Sameer%20Kanikdale
```